# pegas bike model

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have this pegas bike for a long time but i dont know what model it is or if its worth anything these days as it is right now, I m thinking about repairing.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would feel weird to ride because its a "crank forward" layout, or halfway to becoming a recumbent.  Suspect the intent was to allow the one bike to fit a growing child over a much larger number of years.

Answer (score 4):

Doing a little research, Pegas was a Romanian built bicycle brand. They opened in 1972 and are apparently still in business. Some further research show similar images labeled Pegas Mini Strada. The long screw at the fork crown indicates it likely came with a front hand brake. Trying to determine value is generally frowned upon on this site as values change with time and location.